# Design a GUI browser to view a tree

Tags: user-interface, treeview, language-features

I have a large tree. I want to be able to visualize it using a GUI tool. I want the ability to pan and zoom the tree image so that i can focus on part of the tree.

1. Is there an existing tool to achieve this?
2. If not i would like to write a small tool for myself to be able to do this. what is the simplest way of doing this? what computer language should i use?

the image should look something like

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/df/Binary_tree.png

I should be able to zoom and pan the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is to use the [`NetworkX` library for Python](http://networkx.lanl.gov/), coupled with its `matplotlib` visualization. `NetworkX` can render trees to `matplotlib` plots and `matplotlib` allows you to zoom and pan.

Depending on the actual sizes of your trees this may or may not be a complete solution. What's sure is that you can whip it up in a few minutes for rapid prototyping.

Comment: seems good. i will try it out and if it works i will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: that is what i wanted. something easy to learn.